# Как получить текущего пользователя с помощью Spring Boot+JPA

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-jpa

С помощью этого видео пытаюсь сделать аналогичную корзину покупок. На данном этапе пытаюсь получить информацию о товаре(тура) в корзине пользователя.
Дошел до 35 минуты
[введите сюда описание ссылки](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rFSxmKen6aQ)

У меня есть Модель, которая соединяет Тур и Пользователя

```
@Entity 
@Table(name = "cart_items") public class CartItem {  
@Id 
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)  
private int id;
     
@ManyToOne  @JoinColumn(name = "tour_id")  
private Tour tour;
     
@ManyToOne  @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")  
private User user;
@Column(name = "order_date")  private Date date=new Date(); 
//getters and setters 
}
```

Обычная модель Пользователя

```
package com.zaitsava.springboot_touristsite.entity;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Set;


@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "firstname")
    private String firstname;

    @Column(name = "lastname")
    private String lastname;

    @Column(name = "patronymic")
    private String patronymic;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "phone")
    private String phone;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "active")
    private int active;

    @ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name="user_role", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="user_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="role_id"))
    private Set<Role> roles;
    //gettes and setters
}
```

Сервис

```
import com.zaitsava.springboot_touristsite.entity.CartItem;
import com.zaitsava.springboot_touristsite.entity.User;
import com.zaitsava.springboot_touristsite.repository.CartItemRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;

@Service
public class ShoppingCartService {
    @Autowired
    private CartItemRepository cartItemRepository;

    public List<CartItem> cartItemList(User user){
        return cartItemRepository.findByUser(user);
    };
}
```

и Репозиторий:

```
package com.zaitsava.springboot_touristsite.repository;

import com.zaitsava.springboot_touristsite.entity.CartItem;
import com.zaitsava.springboot_touristsite.entity.User;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.List;
@Repository
public interface CartItemRepository extends JpaRepository<CartItem,Integer> {
    public List<CartItem> findByUser(User user);
}
```

Все хорошо добавляется и записывается в бд через Тест
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Когда дошло дело до контроллера показа товара, начались проблемы. Из-за того, что в реализации автора расширяется класс User с разными методами, я не могу получить текущего пользователя в контроллере.
Я пытался сделать

```
package com.zaitsava.springboot_touristsite.controller;

import com.zaitsava.springboot_touristsite.entity.CartItem;
import com.zaitsava.springboot_touristsite.entity.CurrentUser;
import com.zaitsava.springboot_touristsite.entity.User;
import com.zaitsava.springboot_touristsite.service.ShoppingCartService;
import com.zaitsava.springboot_touristsite.service.UserServiceImpl;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;


import java.util.List;

@Controller
public class ShoppingCartController {
    @Autowired
    private ShoppingCartService cartService;
    @Autowired
    private UserServiceImpl userService;

    @GetMapping("/cart")
    public String showCart(Model model,@CurrentUser User user){

        if(user==null) System.out.println("User is null");

        List<CartItem> cartItemList=cartService.cartItemList(user);
        model.addAttribute("cartItems",cartItemList);
        return "user/cart";
    }


}
```

Через аннотацию теккущего пользователя

```
package com.zaitsava.springboot_touristsite.entity;
import org.springframework.security.core.annotation.AuthenticationPrincipal;
import java.lang.annotation.*;

@Target({ElementType.PARAMETER, ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@AuthenticationPrincipal
public @interface CurrentUser {}
```

Однако я получаю пользователя null, даже если захожу через юзера с id 4. Также пытался через параметр

```
 public String showCart(Model model,Principal principal){
        Authentication authentication = (Authentication) principal;
        User user= (User) authentication.getPrincipal();
        //остальной код
}
```

но тогда мне выскакивает ошибка о неправильном преобразовании типа

**Обновлено**
Добавлены настройки Spring Security

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    private final String USERS_QUERY = "select email, password, active from user where email=?";
    private final String ROLES_QUERY = "select u.email, r.role from user u inner join user_role ur on (u.id = ur.user_id) inner join role r on (ur.role_id=r.role_id) where u.email=?";

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.jdbcAuthentication()
                .usersByUsernameQuery(USERS_QUERY)
                .authoritiesByUsernameQuery(ROLES_QUERY)
                .dataSource(dataSource)
                .passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/user/cart").authenticated()
                .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/signup").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("favicon.ico").permitAll()
               /* .antMatchers("/admin/**").access("hasRole('ADMIN')")*/
                .antMatchers("/main/**").hasAuthority("ADMIN").anyRequest()
                .authenticated().and().csrf().disable()
                .formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll().failureUrl("/login?error=true")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
                .usernameParameter("email")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .and().logout()
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
                .and().rememberMe()
                .tokenRepository(persistentTokenRepository())
                .tokenValiditySeconds(60 * 60)
                .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/access_denied");

    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring()
                .antMatchers("/images/**")
                .antMatchers("/fonts/**");
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistentTokenRepository persistentTokenRepository() {
        JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl db = new JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl();
        db.setDataSource(dataSource);

        return db;
    }
}
```

User Controller:

```
package com.zaitsava.springboot_touristsite.controller;


import javax.validation.Valid;

import com.zaitsava.springboot_touristsite.entity.User;
import com.zaitsava.springboot_touristsite.service.UserService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @GetMapping("/signup")
    public ModelAndView signup() {
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        User user = new User();
        model.addObject("user", user);
        model.setViewName("user/signup");
        return model;
    }

    @PostMapping("/signup")
    public ModelAndView createUser(@Valid User user, BindingResult bindingResult) {
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        User userExists = userService.findUserByEmail(user.getEmail());

        if(userExists != null) {
            bindingResult.rejectValue("email", "error.user", "User with this email exists");
        }
        if(bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            model.setViewName("user/signup");
        } else {
            userService.saveUser(user);
            model.addObject("msg", "User succesful register!");
            model.addObject("user", new User());
            model.setViewName("redirect:home/main");
        }

        return model;
    }



    @GetMapping("/home/main")
    public ModelAndView home() {
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        User user = userService.findUserByEmail(auth.getName());

        model.addObject("userName", "Hello,"+user.getFirstname() + " " + user.getLastname()+" "+user.getPatronymic());
        model.setViewName("redirect:/");
        return model;
    }

    @GetMapping("/access_denied")
    public ModelAndView accessDenied() {
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        model.setViewName("errors/access_denied");
        return model;
    }
}
```

Не понимаю, что мне нужно сделать, чтобы нормально работал контроллер

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Посмотрел контролллер User метод home(), и переделал так для showCart() в ShoppingCartController

```
@GetMapping("/cart")
public String showCart(Model model){
    Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    User user = userService.findUserByEmail(auth.getName());
    if(user==null) System.out.println("User is null");
    List<CartItem> cartItemList=cartService.cartItemList(user);
    model.addAttribute("cartItems",cartItemList);
    return "user/cart";
}
```

Теперь по ссылке /cart отображается связь с товаром для текущего пользователя